# When aliasing a function, I do not see composite types

Tags: postgresql

I create table `gs`:

```
foo=>create table gs as select generate_subscripts('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::integer[],2);
```

I alias the table and the column:

```
foo=> select s.a from gs s(a);
 a
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

If I only alias the table, I see composite types:

```
foo=> select s from gs s;
  s
-----
 (1)
 (2)
 (3)
(3 rows)
```

But when I only alias a function as if it was a table, I do not see composite types, but it is as if I had aliased a table and column:

```
foo=>  select s from generate_subscripts('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::integer[],2) s;
 s 
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

I do not understand why I do not see composite types instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set returning functions (or table functions, SRF) are treated differently than actual relations (tables, views, etc.). [Especially, when they return only one column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) (a *base type*):

> **If no `table_alias` is specified, the function name is used as the table name**; in the case of a `ROWS FROM()` construct, the first function's name is used.
>
> **If column aliases are not supplied, then for a function returning a base data type, the column name is also the same as the function name**. For a function returning a composite type, the result columns get the names of the individual attributes of the type.

What is not covered though, is the case, when you supply a table alias, but not  a column alias (for a single-columned SRF). In that case, the column alias will be the same as the table alias, so you can't access the function's row-type (composite type) explicitly (its reference is hidden by the column alias).

```
select s from generate_subscripts('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::integer[],2) s;
-- "s" is both a column alias and a table alias here, so:
select s.s from generate_subscripts('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::integer[],2) s;
-- is also valid
```

More intriguing however, is that when you use an explicit table alias **and** an explicit column alias for a single-columned SRF, the table alias also becomes a column alias (its type will be the base type, not a row-type -- composite type).

```
select s, a from generate_subscripts('{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'::integer[],2) s(a);

+---+---+
| s | a |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

I'm not sure though if it's a bug, or just an undocumented "feature".

http://rextester.com/VJOBI47962

Comment: Intriguing. Also, could you explain to me how you created http://rextester.com/VJOBI47962? Which programs did you use to create it? How do you send the commands in the editor to postgres?

Comment: @ericj rextester is the program itself. it's an online tool, where you can send some command/statements to rextester's own database (or if you choose another language, then for that language's interpreter/compiler). You can run the code you created with the "run it" button below. there are also a few other tools just like that, e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com http://dbfiddle.uk